# Restricciones en el getline C++

Tags: c++

El programa consiste en ir recogiendo los nombres de personas,(Solo sus nombres, no apellidos) mostrandolos por pantalla, hasta encontrar un string que sea 'FIN'.

Formato del programa:
(nombre,apellido)

Ejemplo:

Manuel,Perez
Pepe,Ginebra
Lola,Flores
 FIN

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string aux;
  getline(cin,aux,',');

  while(aux != "FIN")
  {
   cout << aux;
   getline(cin,aux,',');
  }

return 0;
}
```

Como solo queremos el nombre, usamos un

> getline(cin,aux,',')

que termine al encontrar una coma, excluyendo a esta.                               No obstante, en el momento en que introduzcamos 'FIN', el getline seguira esperando una coma y hasta que no sea introducida el programa no terminara.

¿Alguna sugerencia para arreglar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución pasa por recibir toda la cadena perteneciente a la línea, y tratar esta cadena hasta el carácter ','.
Puedes utilizar el siguiente código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string aux;
  getline(cin,aux);

  while(aux != "FIN")
  {


   std::string::size_type filePos = aux.rfind(',');
   std::string name = aux.substr(0,filePos);

    cout << name;
   getline(cin,aux);
  }
  cout<<aux;

    return 0;
}
```